# Drupal 8 user image browser

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there a fairly standard strategy in Drupal 8 for uploading images (or other files) per user, that is presenting a user with only his/her images when editing an article, and allowing a user to upload images, which are then marked as his?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use the entity_browser and inline entity form. I filter the view of the entity browser to show only media entities created by the current user. This allows me to have a kind of "user library" of media items. There are a lot more possibilities along this line btw. You can make custom entity browser views with multiple criteria, and even search forms.

Since I can use inline entity form with the browser it provides a rather elegant interface for the whole thing.

If you want, you can also hack in, or subclass the media entity to save to custom locations, like user subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I know the answer -- but to help clarify -- are you asking if each user can basically have their own personal media library, and if they upload new images, it is also added to a media library that only they can see?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I have already noticed that I can use the entity browser and modify its view to filter by uid, but actually I need more: I need to be able to protect a media_entity_image with drupal's permissions. I think  I may have to subclass media_entity_image and change some things. I will want an image directory per user, and access control.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to create a new file type and then limit the permissions on that file type so that users can only view their own files. Not sure about the directory per user, unless you could somehow specify that using tokens.